# Does CloudFront distribution need a replica in multi-region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudfront

I am working on a multi-region solution for my current architecture. We use CloudFormation for defining the infrastructure. A piece of that architecture is a Cloudfront distribution which takes the user to an S3 bucket. I know I will have to create a failover for S3, in case one of the regions goes down, but what about CF distribution? I know CF is a global service, so it doesn't need a replica?

Here's the CF distribution we have:

```
IVRSpeechContentCFDistro:
    Type: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution
    Properties:
      DistributionConfig:
        Aliases:
          - !FindInMap [ EnvMappings, !Ref StageName, domain ]
        HttpVersion: http2
        ViewerCertificate:
          AcmCertificateArn: !FindInMap [ EnvMappings, !Ref StageName, ssl ]
          MinimumProtocolVersion: TLSv1.2_2021
          SslSupportMethod: sni-only
        Enabled: True
        DefaultCacheBehavior:
          CachePolicyId: xxxxxx
          AllowedMethods:
            - GET
            - HEAD
            - OPTIONS
          TargetOriginId: !Sub "xxxxxx"
          ViewerProtocolPolicy: https-only
        Origins:
          - Id: !Sub "xxxxxxx"
            DomainName: !GetAtt bucket.RegionalDomainName
            S3OriginConfig:
              OriginAccessIdentity: !Sub
                - "origin-access-identity/cloudfront/${ID}"
                - { ID: !Ref identity }
```

Comment: I think you need to use Lambda@Edge with one CloudFront distribution as per this blog https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/using-amazon-cloudfront-with-multi-region-amazon-s3-origins/

Comment: What do you mean by "replica" of CoudFront? Like the same CF distro but in different region?

Comment: @Marcin What I mean by replica is the copy/another instance in another region, yes.

Comment: @Sri why do you think I should be using Lambda@Edge? Can you explain?

Comment: I have to emphasize that my concern here is that if CF goes down, we don't have another distribution available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudFront is **global** service, so you can't make any "replica" of it in other region, just like you can't make a "replica" of IAM or Route53. But you can setup [CloudFront origin failover](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/disaster-recovery-resiliency.html). This makes it that:

> CloudFront automatically switches to the second origin when the primary origin returns specific HTTP status code failure responses.

Comment: Would I need Lambda@Edge for this solution at all? Or will cloudfront know automatically to which bucket to redirect in case there's one region failure?

Comment: @elena CloudFront origin failover is automatic. That's the entire point of this feature.